# Problems with the authentication to a REST service use `HttpClient` from an `WP8` App

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8

I am trying to conect my app with some Rest services that requires authentication and I am having some problems. I using the `HttpClient` class and it works fine with the services that do not need this authentication like the login or the signup. I think that the problem is that I need to specify a schema in the  `AuthenticationHeaderValue` object and this schema goes into the header. The result of the header is like this "Authorization: Authorization a81b4974-f328-44e0-901a-95e29fb672aa:sKJQgOqJswCLHlibsMGRYZb/dlkyPzVnvs9uqqx5ToM=" and what the server is looking for is something like "Authorization: a81b4974-f328-44e0-901a-95e29fb672aa:sKJQgOqJswCLHlibsMGRYZb/dlkyPzVnvs9uqqx5ToM="
Here is the code that I am using:

```
public async void addProject(string name) 
{
    string service = "/service/project/add";
    string serviceURL = "/pwpcloud"+service;
    StringBuilder parametersBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    parametersBuilder.Append("{\"name\":\"" + name + "\",");
    parametersBuilder.Append("\"description\":\"" + "projectDescription" + "\",");
    parametersBuilder.Append("\"sparsePath\":\"" + "fasdd" + "\",");
    parametersBuilder.Append("\"densePath\":\"" + "asdf" + "\",");
    parametersBuilder.Append("\"matchFormat\":\"" + "asdf" + "\",");
    parametersBuilder.Append("\"metadata\":\"" + "aaaaa" + "\",");
    parametersBuilder.Append("\"user\":\"" + mLoginData.getUserID() + "\"}");

    string parameters = parametersBuilder.ToString();

    HttpClient restClient = new HttpClient();
    restClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(mBaseURL);
    restClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    //falta la autenticacion
    setAuthorization(restClient, service, WEBSERVICE_REQUEST_TYPE_POST);
    HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, serviceURL);
    req.Content = new StringContent(parameters, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    string responseBodyAsText = "";
    try
    {
        response = await restClient.SendAsync(req);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        string ex = e.Message;
    }
}

public void setAuthorization(HttpClient request, string service, int reqType, string token, string userID)
{
    //Date OK
    string date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");

    //nonce OK
    Random random = new Random();
    String nonce = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        string randomValue = (1111 + random.Next() % (9999 - 1111)).ToString();
        nonce = nonce + randomValue;
    }
    //type OK
    string type = "";
    if (reqType == WEBSERVICE_REQUEST_TYPE_GET)
    {
        type = "GET";
    }
    else
    {
        type = "POST";
    }

    //Authorization:
    string stringToHash = token + ":" + service + "," + type + "," + date + "," + nonce;
    string authorizationCrypted = encryptStringSHA256(stringToHash);
    //string authorization = userID + ":" + authorizationCrypted;
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", string.Format("{0}:{1}", userID, authorizationCrypted));

    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-rest-date", date);
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("nonce", nonce);
}
public static string encryptStringSHA256(string stringToEncrypt)
{
    var hash = new SHA256Managed();

    byte[] stringHash = StringToAscii(stringToEncrypt);
    byte[] encryptedString = hash.ComputeHash(stringHash);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedString);
}

//Metodo para convertir string a bytes ascii NO IMPLEMENTADO POR DEFECTO EN EL API DE WINDOWS PHONE
public static byte[] StringToAscii(string s)
{
    byte[] retval = new byte[s.Length];
    for (int ix = 0; ix < s.Length; ++ix)
    {
        char ch = s[ix];
        if (ch <= 0x7f) retval[ix] = (byte)ch;
        else retval[ix] = (byte)'?';
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Key",value)` method. this is the code:

```
public void setAuthorization(HttpClient request, string service, int reqType, string token, string userID)
{
    //Date OK
    string date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");

    //nonce OK
    Random random = new Random();
    String nonce = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        string randomValue = (1111 + random.Next() % (9999 - 1111)).ToString();
        nonce = nonce + randomValue;
    }
    //type OK
    string type = "";
    if (reqType == WEBSERVICE_REQUEST_TYPE_GET)
    {
        type = "GET";
    }
    else
    {
        type = "POST";
    }

    //Authorization:
    string stringToHash = token + ":" + service + "," + type + "," + date + "," + nonce;
    string authorizationCrypted = encryptStringSHA256(stringToHash);
    string authorization = userID + ":" + authorizationCrypted;
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-rest-date", date);
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authorization);
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("nonce", nonce);
}
```