# Http multipart request from windows phone 8 to send an text and an image using C# in WP8

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8, multipartform-data

I need make a multipart post request to a Rest service to send an image and a string but I can't do the code work.  this is the code and I make a comment with capital letters where I get the exception and the exception message in the catch block.

```
public async Task<bool> addImages(Project project)
{
    bool success = false;
    string uuid = project.uuid;
    if (uuid.Equals(""))
    {

        return success;
    }

    mUploadedImages = 0;
    mProject = project;
    string service = "service/imagen-project/add";
    string serviceURL = mBaseURL + "/pwpcloud/" + service;


    //build the REST request
    // HTTP web request
    string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceURL);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

    //Calculate the total size of the upload content.
    string boundaryStringLine = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    byte[] boundaryStringLineBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(boundaryStringLine);

    string lastBoundaryStringLine = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
    byte[] lastBoundaryStringLineBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(lastBoundaryStringLine);

    // Get the byte array of the myFileDescription content disposition
    string myFileDescriptionContentDisposition = String.Format(
        "Content-Dis-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n","project");
    byte[] myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myFileDescriptionContentDisposition);
    byte[] uuidBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(project.uuid);

    string fileUrl = "isostore:/" + project.Name + "_ID" + project.ID + "_Pictures/Pic_1.jpg";
    string fileName = project.Name + "_ID" + project.ID + "_Pictures/Pic_1.jpg";

    string myFileContentDisposition = String.Format("Content-Dis-data;name=\"{0}\"; " + 
        "filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n", "myFile", Path.GetFileName(fileUrl), "image/png");
    byte[] myFileContentDispositionBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myFileContentDisposition);

    IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    var fileStream = isoStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
    // Calculate the total size of the HTTP request
    long totalRequestBodySize = boundaryStringLineBytes.Length * 2 + lastBoundaryStringLineBytes.Length + myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes.Length + uuidBytes.Length +
        +myFileContentDispositionBytes.Length + imageBytes.Length;
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = totalRequestBodySize;

    //Set cripted authorization --  WORKS FINE
    setAuthorization(httpWebRequest, service, WEBSERVICE_REQUEST_TYPE_POST);

    // Write the request Asynchronously 
    using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream, httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
    {
        // Send the file description content disposition over to the server
        await stream.WriteAsync(boundaryStringLineBytes, 0, boundaryStringLineBytes.Length);
        await stream.WriteAsync(myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes, 0, myFileDescriptionContentDisposition.Length);
        await stream.WriteAsync(uuidBytes, 0, uuidBytes.Length);

        // Send the file content disposition over to the server
        await stream.WriteAsync(boundaryStringLineBytes, 0, boundaryStringLineBytes.Length);
        await stream.WriteAsync(myFileContentDispositionBytes, 0, myFileContentDispositionBytes.Length);

        fileStream.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        await stream.WriteAsync(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        fileStream.Close();

        // Send the last part of the HTTP request body
        await stream.WriteAsync(lastBoundaryStringLineBytes, 0, lastBoundaryStringLineBytes.Length);

    }
    try
    {
        var responseTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse, httpWebRequest.EndGetResponse, null);
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)await responseTask) //I GET THE EXCEPCION HERE (
        {
            string data;

            // Read the response into a Stream object. 
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            responseStream.Close();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string err = e.Message; // err = "The remote server returned an error: NotFound" but the ServiceURL is ok
        throw;
    }

    return success;
}
```

I could run this in a desktop program using C++ but I couldn't find any class to do it in C# using the same "sctructure". This is the C++ code:

```
void WebServicesClient::addImages(PW::Project *project){
QString uuid = project->getCloudUUID();                         

if (uuid.isEmpty()) /// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    return;

mUploadedImages = 0;
mProject = project;

QNetworkRequest request;
QString serviceURL = mBaseURL+"/service/imagen-project/add";
request.setUrl(QUrl(serviceURL));
//    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "multipart/form-data");

QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

QHttpPart textPart;
textPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"project\""));
textPart.setBody(uuid.toAscii());

QHttpPart imagePart;
imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("image/png"));
QString fileName =  project->getImages().at(0)->getFileName();
QString header = "form-data; name=\"file\"";
header += "; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"";
imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant(header));
QFile *file = new QFile(project->getImages().at(0)->getFullPath());
file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
imagePart.setBodyDevice(file);
file->setParent(multiPart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multiPart

multiPart->append(textPart);
multiPart->append(imagePart);

setAuthorization(request, "service/imagen-project/add", WEBSERVICE_REQUEST_TYPE_POST); 
QObject::connect(mNetwork, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)),
                 this, SLOT(onAddImageFinished(QNetworkReply*)));       
emit statusChanged(0, "Uploading " + project->getImages().at(0)->getFileName()); 

QNetworkReply *reply = mNetwork->post(request,multiPart);
```

}

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: See `HttpClient` and `MultipartContent` classes instead of forming it with string operations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problems is that I need a specific authentication that I can't do with the `HttpClient`. I will take a look to `MultipartContent`. Can I use it with `HttpWebRequest`?? Thanks!

Comment: Luis, you prepare a multipartContent and post it with HttpClient. Not to use with HttpWebRequest.

Comment: I can't do that because I have to send an authentication header with no scheme and the HttpClient doesn't allow me to do this. I need find an alternative

Comment: @EZI the problem that I have with the `httpClient` class is this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508168/problems-with-the-authentication-to-a-rest-service-use-httpclient-from-an-wp8 I solved it using the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse clases

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but doesn't `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation` work?

Comment: @EZI I didn't try with this method until now and it works!! the connection  is really easier using this class. Now I will try with the MultipartContent to send the multipart request. Thanks a lot!